# Finding the location where a photosphere was taken

Tags: math, geometry, polar-coordinates, 360-degrees, 360-panorama

I have a room with four corners (c1, c2, c3, c4), for each of which I have coordinates.

A user takes a photosphere - a 360-degree image - in this room. (We do not have the coordinates of the photosphere's location.) They then identify the room corners by clicking on the image. This gives us four angles (a1, a2, a3, a4).

From this data, I would like to find the most likely location where the photosphere was taken, as xy coordinates. What's the best way to do this?

<sub>(Disclaimer: I'm a halfway competent programmer but not a great mathematician, so please excuse me if I need to follow up on any particular points of understanding. Thank you!)</sub>

---

Edit 1: I've been trying to get @meowgoesthedog's really helpful solution working. Here it is (in Ruby, but it'd be pretty much the same in any other language) with some sample data:

```
c1 = [70.38017162671083, 573.9210230366474]
c2 = [62.14926043346433, 573.9210230601221]
c3 = [62.170859502652874, 566.273256963365]
c4 = [70.41870117287603, 566.2827951694268]

a1 = 0.7162475014121918
a2 = 3.076344266497204
a3 = 4.964159781307695
a4 = 5.859686474799228

a = Math.sin(a1) +Math.sin(a2)
b =-Math.cos(a1) -Math.cos(a2)
c = Math.sin(a3) +Math.sin(a4)
d =-Math.cos(a3) -Math.cos(a4)

e = Math.sin(a1)*c1[0] + Math.sin(a2)*c2[0] - Math.cos(a1)*c1[1] - Math.cos(a2)*c2[1]
f = Math.sin(a3)*c3[0] + Math.sin(a4)*c4[0] - Math.cos(a3)*c3[1] - Math.cos(a4)*c4[1]

x = (d*e - b*f) / (a*d - b*c)
y = (a*f - c*e) / (a*d - b*c)
```

However, the results aren't what I'd expect: in this case, x is 77.29614012577807 and y is 551.2264007863547. Both of these are outside the bounding box of the room (roughly x 62-70, y 566-574) where the camera is placed.

Calculating the angle from x,y to the corners c1 c2 c3 c4, which should result in (roughly) a1 a2 a3 a4, comes up with very different results:

```
puts Math.atan2(c1[1]-y, c1[0]-x)
> 1.8665964276063274
```

Is there anything obvious you can see that I'm doing wrong? Thank you again!

Comment: Adding more relevant tags like `image-processing` and `opencv` might help. What do these 4 angles represent?

Comment: The angles are essentially the angles of polar coordinates, where the photosphere location is the origin, and the coordinate represents a corner.

(Thanks for the hint - will search for some more relevant tags!)

Comment: Just to clarify - these are angles in the XY plane? If not then you may also need the height info. And also, which angles correspond to which sides?

Comment: Yes, just in the XY plane (so polar rather than spherical, I guess). a1 is the angle from the photosphere to room corner c1, a2 to c2, and so on.

Comment: @SparrowhawkDisaster: where do you measure those angles ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: the angles are from the origin of the photosphere (i.e. where the camera is standing) to the points on the edge of the photosphere (i.e. the corners of the walls). The user clicks to identify these corners. (Technically I'm using photo-sphere-viewer.js and taking the .longitude property from the user's clicks.)